# Finding total parameter space which make an expression negative

Tags: complex

Consider below expression:

$-a -b(1- 2\sin^2\theta) \pm Im\bigg(\sqrt{ -(a(1- 2\sin^2\theta))^2-c \sin \theta}\bigg)$

in which $a$ and $b$ and $c$ is real. Could anyone introduce complete parameter space in which above expression be negativ?

Comment: it is not possible because the values of a,b and c are not known @zhk

Comment: I need an expression instead of table @zhk

Comment: it is correct, but I don't know how to use it @zhk

Comment: I don't' have (1 - 2*Sin[\[Theta]]^2))^2 in the expression @zhk

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit what the original problem is, that you're trying to solve, that lead to this equation? It might be that your problem is easier to solve in a different form. In theory `Resolve[ForAll[\[Theta], -a - b (1 - 2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) + 
   Im[Sqrt[-(-a + b (1 - 2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2))^2 - c Sin[\[Theta]]]] < 
  0], Reals]` would be the way to go, but i'm not sure Mathematica can give you a simple solution when the input is in the current form.

Comment: `ImplicitRegion[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited for clarity:

Firstly, there are no points in the `{a, b, c}`-parameter space for which your expression is negative for all values of `θ`. To see this, define the function

```
f[a_, b_, c_, θ_, k_] := -a - b (1 - 2 Sin[θ]^2) + 
  (-1)^k Im[Sqrt[-(-a + b (1 - 2 Sin[θ]^2))^2 - c Sin[θ]^2]]
```

so that `k = 1, 2` correspond to the `-` and `+` in your expression. Then you can find the constraints on `a`, `b` and `c` for which `f < 0` by:

```
sol1 = FullSimplify[
  Reduce[{f[a, b, c, θ, 1] < 0 && a > 0 && b > 0}, {a, b, c}, Reals]]
sol2 = FullSimplify[
  Reduce[{f[a, b, c, θ, 2] < 0 && a > 0 && b > 0}, {a, b, c}, Reals]]
```

It turns out that `sol1` and `sol2` are identical:

```
sol1 === sol2
(* True *)
```

To show that there are no parameters that yield `f < 0` for all `θ`, calculate the conditions given by `sol1` for `θ = 0` and `θ = π/2`:

```
Reduce[sol1 /. θ -> 0, Reals]
Reduce[sol1 /. θ -> π/2, Reals]
```

> b > 0 && a == b
>
> a > 0 && 0 < b < a && c <= -a^2 - 2 a b - b^2

So if `θ = 0`, `f < 0` only if `a = b > 0`. And for `θ = π/2`, `f < 0` only if `a > b > 0`. Clearly there are no `{a, b}` pairs that can satisfy both these constraints, so there are no values of `a` and `b` that allow `f` to be negative for all values of `θ`.

To better understand how the sign of `f` changes over regions of `{a, b, c}`-space you can make a plot that shows, for a given `θ`, the `{a, b, c}` points that correspond to negative `f`:

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot3D[sol1 /. θ -> ϕ, {a, 0, 5}, {b, 0, 5}, {c, -100, 0}, AxesLabel -> {a, b, c}], 
 {{ϕ, 0.02}, -2 π, 2 π}]
```

[image]

[image]

The coloured regions are the points `{a, b, c}` for which `f[a, b, c, θ] < 0`. (`ϕ` is the same as `θ` -- I just had to change the variable name for the plot).

Where you go from here depends (as @ThiesHeidecke pointed out) on the original problem that gave rise to this question.

Comment: What are ble and brown parts in the output

Comment: @saranj I've made some edits. Hope it's clearer now.